# Javascript queue implementation with linkedlist

Tags: javascript

```
class Node {
    constructor(value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}


class Queue{
    constructor(){
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    enqueue(value){
        const newNode = new Node(value)
        if(this.length === 0){
            this.first = newNode;
            this.last = newNode;
        } else {
            this.last.next = newNode;
            this.last = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
}

const myQueue = new Queue();
myQueue.enqueue('a')
myQueue.enqueue('b')
```

Here I am implementing **Queue** with linkedlists.
In else block of **enqueue()** method i am not assigning anything to 
**this.first** i am only assigning to **this.last**

How my **this.first** if changing.

Please have a look.

How **this.first** is changing without even touching it.

Actually the answer is correct but, I am not able to understand
the logic.

Comment: You are assigning to `this.last.next` but when you insert `b` `this.last` === `this.first`.

Comment: How is becomes this.last === this.first ?

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere?

Comment: You assign both to the same reference: `this.first = newNode; this.last = newNode;`. Changing `this.first` changes properties on `newNode` -- so does changing `this.last`.

Comment: Okk. got it. Thanks

Comment: Your logic is may be wrong, try to add 3rd element, its replacing 2nd element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
this.first = newNode;
this.last = newNode;
```

You are setting the **REFERENCE** to `this.first` and `this.last` to the same object. Basically,  `this.first` and `this.last` have the same memory address.

So, next time you are calling:

```
this.last.next = newNode;
this.last = newNode;
```

`this.last.next` modifies the object reference of the previous `newNode`, whose memory address is same as `this.first`. So, when you change in `this.last` it gets modified also in `this.first`.